# How to change the property of a specific object when buttonclick occurs, using a PUT-method (JSON) in react and springboot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have made some code inside of the spring boot back-end application which allows me to change a property of a specific object, this property which needs to be changed is the "status" property:

```
@Entity
public class Pakketje {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int code;
    private String status = "In magazijn";

    public Pakketje() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

To change the property of that object, i will need to state the ID of that object (i think) inside of the react frontend application, and then fetch the PUT-method.

I will show you the method to change the property inside of my spring boot back-end application, this method can be found in the 'Service' class. 'bestaandPakketje' means existing pakketje.

```
  @Override
    public Pakketje getPakketjeById(int id) {
    return pakketjeRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Pakketje statusOnderweg(Pakketje pakketje) {
    Pakketje bestaandPakketje = pakketjeRepository.findById(pakketje.getId()).orElse(null);
    bestaandPakketje.setStatus(pakketje.getStatus());
    return pakketjeRepository.save(bestaandPakketje);
    }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
public class PakketjeController {
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired 
    private PakketjeService pakketjeService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestBody Pakketje pakketje) {
        pakketjeService.pakketjeOpslaan(pakketje);
        return "Pakketje opgeslagen!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Pakketje> getAllePakketjes(){
        return pakketjeService.getAllePakketjes();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
    public Pakketje findPakketjeById(int id) {
        return pakketjeService.getPakketjeById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateOnderweg")
    public Pakketje statusIsOnderweg(@RequestBody Pakketje pakketje) {
        return pakketjeService.statusOnderweg(pakketje);
    }
}
```

Now the next step is verry hard for me. Each 'pakketje' has his own button which can be clicked to change the property (I will upload the picture so please check it). When that button is clicked the property automatically should change from "In magazijn "to "onderweg".

I would appreciate some help!

[image: Here you can see that for each button click of an object the PUT-method should be applied and change the status of ONLY that specific object]

Comment: `onClick` event is fired on the front-end, so you need to add `onClick` handler in your  javascript code (in your case, it's React library). So, when user click the button, this event is firen. So, in event handler function you can call your corresponding api endpoint to do some logic on your back-end side (in your case, it's Java Spring)

Comment: Do you want to update `onClick` or when you get a response from the server with the new object and update the object in React? In any cases, we would need to see the reactjs code to tell you how to update.